# SP13: Dataview Webpart &nbsp

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, data-view-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a Dataview Webpart that is used in a page that originated in SP07 however was migrated to 2013 version.  Looking at the xsl script there are no hard spaces are indicated by using &nbsp or `<p>`.  The problem is when the Webpart is applied to the page &nbsp appears randomly through the text.  For an example see below.

My question is since the page originated in 2007 version would I be able to fix the issue in designer 2013?

In 2007 it was known to wrap text better to use `<xsl:text disableoutputescaping="yes">` however as mentioned there are no indication of spaces found the xsl script.  Would still use thus approach in SP13?

Would "break" indicated with "br" cause the same issue to occur?

Example

This is an example.  This is &nbsp an example.  This is an example.  This is an example. &nbsp.  This is an example.

Thanks in advance for your help!